# Why FragmentLoginBinding returns null?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-viewbinding

I'm building a chat application using Stream SDK. I'm using a BindingFrament from which all fragments can inherit and get initialize the binding for each fragment in the bindingFragment class using Generics. But it give nullPointerException.

```
package com.example.streamchat.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding
import com.example.streamchat.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding

abstract class BindingFragment<out T : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: ViewBinding? = null
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    protected val binding: T
        get() = _binding as T

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = bindingInflater(inflater)
        return _binding!!.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    protected abstract val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> ViewBinding
}
```

Login Fragment :

```
package com.example.streamchat.ui.login

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewDebug.FlagToString
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.core.widget.addTextChangedListener
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding
import com.example.streamchat.R
import com.example.streamchat.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding
import com.example.streamchat.ui.BindingFragment
import com.example.streamchat.utils.Constants
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.security.cert.TrustAnchor

@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginFragment : BindingFragment<FragmentLoginBinding>() {

    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> ViewBinding
        get() = FragmentLoginBinding::inflate

    private val viewModel : LoginViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding.btnConfirm.setOnClickListener{
            setUpConnectingUIState()
            viewModel.connectUser(binding.etUsername.text.toString())

        }

        binding.etUsername.addTextChangedListener {
            binding.etUsername.error = null
        }

        subscribeToEvents()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setUpConnectingUIState(){
        binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
        binding.btnConfirm.isVisible = false
    }

    private fun setUpIdealUIState(){
        binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
        binding.btnConfirm.isVisible = true
    }

    private fun subscribeToEvents(){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.logInEvent.collect{event ->
                when(event){
                    is LoginViewModel.LogInEvent.ErrorInputTooShort->{
                        setUpIdealUIState()
                        binding.etUsername.error =
                            getString(R.string.error_username_too_short,Constants.MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH)
                    }
                    is LoginViewModel.LogInEvent.ErrorLogIn->{
                        setUpIdealUIState()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            event.error,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                    is LoginViewModel.LogInEvent.Success->{
                        setUpIdealUIState()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code it gives me this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.streamchat, PID: 6243
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type T of com.example.streamchat.ui.BindingFragment
        at com.example.streamchat.ui.BindingFragment.getBinding(BindingFragment.kt:17)
        at com.example.streamchat.ui.login.LoginFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.kt:37)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LoginFragment is inheriting from BindingFragment and both these functions are overriding onCreateView(). So, in the LoginFragment we need to call
 `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)`
So that the code we wrote in BindingFragment can run and initialize the binding variable.

Binding Fragment:

```
abstract class BindingFragment<T : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: T? = null
    lateinit var binding : T

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        _binding = bindingInflater(inflater, container)
        binding = _binding!!
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    abstract fun bindingInflater(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): T
}
```

LoginFragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve your problem.

```
abstract class BindingFragment<T : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: T? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = bindingInflater(inflater, container)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    abstract fun bindingInflater(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): T
}
```

Usage :

```
override fun bindingInflater(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): FragmentLoginBinding {
    return FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
}
```

Comment: It's still returning nullPointerException